# Skip test coverage while deploying to sandboxes and production

Tags: code-coverage, unlocked-package

I would like to deploy to my sandboxes and production a library called [fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common); however, I do not want to include the test or run the test code, anyways, it is a library and we will never change the source code.

I am looking at the [Org-Dependent Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_org_dependent.htm), and see that one could skip the test coverage for the package but it is not clear if this would skip test coverage during deployment to sandbox and production:

[image]

Can you confirm I can achieve my goal by using Org-Dependent Unlocked Packages? if not please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests are never required for installation to a Sandbox, so you don't need to worry about that. Org-Dependent Unlocked Packages are really only necessary for your own metadata. I recommend using a normal Unlocked Package for fflib.

To do this efficiently, create a main project directory, then clone both ApexMocks and fflib into this project directory. Remove the sfdx project modules and so on from the main directory of each, and put their paths into the main directory, then create your packages. I've actually done this before, it's pretty trivial to do.

So, basically, you start with setting up your directories:

```
cd ~/workspace
sfdx force:project:create -n myOrg
cd myOrg
git init
git submodule add https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks.git
git submodule add https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common.git
```

Next, set your default dev hub org:

```
sfdx force:config:set defaultdevhubusername=myDevHubAlias
```

After that, clean up some files you don't need:

```
rm fflib-apex-mocks/sfdx-project.json
rm fflib-apex-common/sfdx-project.json
```

Then edit the new sfdx-project.json file:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "fflib-apex-common/sfdx-source",
      "package": "fflibApexCommon",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "path": "fflib-apex-mocks/sfdx-source",
      "package": "fflibApexMocks",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "name": "myOrg",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "52.0"
}
```

Next, create two new packages:

```
sfdx force:package:create -n fflibApexMocks -t Unlocked -r fflib-apex-mocks/sfdx-source/
sfdx force:package:create -n fflibApexCommon -t Unlocked -r fflib-apex-common/sfdx-source/
```

And assign the dependency to the fflibApexCommon in sfdx-project.json:

```
{
  "path": "fflib-apex-common/sfdx-source",
  "package": "fflibApexCommon",
  "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "package": "fflibApexMocks", 
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST"
    }
  ],
  "default": false
},
```

You need to do this after creating the packages to avoid errors.

Now, you will create the package versions:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -w 100 -x -p fflibApexMocks -c
sfdx force:package:version:create -w 100 -x -p fflibApexCommon -c
```

This step here creates your code coverage.

And finally, you need to promote the package versions to install in production:

```
sfdx force:package:version:promote -p fflibApexMocks@0.1.0-1
sfdx force:package:version:promote -p fflibApexCommon@0.1.0-1
```

Once you get through all these steps, you'll be ready to install your packages. No code coverage will be required on install, because it was already covered when we created the package version and promoted the packages.

Finally, you can commit your files so you safely continue development:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid unit test while installing the unlock package in production?

Comment: @Cubancoffee Promoted, unlocked packages do not run their tests during installation, as they are already pre-validated.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox you saved my day :).